# Transformed LiveData with distinctUntilChanged() returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

Let's say we have a simple model class:

```
data class Model(val value: Int)
```

and we wrap this model into `LiveData`:

```
val model1 = MutableLiveData<Model>()
```

Now we can create a second variable that uses `model1`:

```
val model2 = model1.distinctUntilChanged()
```

and let's set value to `model1` and print values for both models"

```
model1.value = Model(0)
print(model1.value.toString()) // Model(value=0)
print(model2.value.toString()) // null
```

The issue is that `model2.value` is null. Of course if I remove distinctUntilChanged() transformation, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `observe` LiveData to have it populate its `value` from another `MutableLiveData` instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is that? I thought that `distinctUntilChanged()` creates new `MediatorLiveData` that observes the original `LiveData` and set the populated value to its own value.

Comment: It doesn't start observing until something starts observing it